# Ошибка при запуске Java Spring Boot проекта на Docker. Exception during pool initialization

Tags: java, mysql, nginx, docker, spring-boot

Имеется сервер ubuntu с установленным Docker. Есть проект (React, Java Spring). При docker-compose up в логах появляется следующая ошибка:

```
2022-08-31 11:23:30,516 ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-server:
    restart: always
    container_name: 'nginx-server'
    image: 'hermanvfx/nginx:latest'
    depends_on:
      - front_app
    ports:
      - '80:80'

  front_app:
    container_name: 'project-avito4_1_front'
    image: 'hermanvfx/avito4_1_front:latest'
#    ports:
#      - '3000:3000'
  mysql:
    container_name: 'mysql-image'
    image: 'hermanvfx/mysql:latest'
    environment:
      - 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root'
      - 'MYSQL_DATABASE=platform'

  app:
    container_name: 'project-avito4_1_back'
    image: 'hermanvfx/avito4_1_app:latest'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - '8888:8888'
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql-image:3306/platform?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PLATFORM=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8888
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.storage_engine=innodb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/platform?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true&\
  useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

[image: Изображение ошибок:]

Comment: там же у вас все белым по черному написано: `root` убил `mysql`, после чего спринг не наблюдая признаков жизни соединений с mysql начал ругаться, что ответа от мускула нет

Comment: ну и по ходу у вас просто база сдохла...попробуйте запустить отдельный контейнер с mysql и понаблюдайте за ним

Comment: скорее всего при попытке подняться - он также покрашится...хотя, конечно, может быть и такое, что он крашнулся при попытке выполнения каких-то операций...в любом случае проблема на стороне мускула, как мне кажеться

Comment: Если вручную добавить таблицы в базу данных, то при docker-compose up он их удалит, следовательно подключение к базе есть. Если я правильно понял

Comment: [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
Если вы об этой строчке, то она есть и при старте полностью рабочего проекта

Comment: нет...я не про эту строчку,  в которой говориться что mysqld shutting down by user root

Comment: а вот удалит или УДАЛЯЛ - вам и предстоит разобраться...а для этого повтыкайте контейнер mysql отдельно (с тем же VOLUME) и попытаетесь с этой базой поработать

Comment: закомментируйте в `docker-compose.yml` все помимо mysql, подымите и попробуйте поработать и посмотрите что и как

Comment: расскажите потом- что получилось

Comment: Сделал как вы и сказали, удалил из docker-compose.yml всё кроме mysql, добавил порт для внешнего подключения. Подключился через MySql Workbench, добавил таблицы, перезапустил контейнер, созданные мною таблицы остались.

Comment: Со спрингом продолжает крашиться?

Comment: Да, со спрингом всё по прежнему. У нас есть две версии этого спринг проекта. Старая и новая. Если запускать эти проекты из idea они работают. Из под docker запускается только старая версия проекта. К старой версии к сожалению доступа нет

Comment: А Что изменилось?.. Есть мысли?

Comment: docker-compose.yml не менялся точно. pom тоже. Добавилось несколько контроллеров, сущностей entity.

Comment: в следствие всего этого спринг не может создать таблицы:
```
project-avito4_1_back | org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
project-avito4_1_back |     alter table addrezz
project-avito4_1_back |        drop
project-avito4_1_back |        foreign key FK1loijl4os4xjocerqd23g6ca1" via JDBC Statement
```

Comment: mysql контейнер так устроен, что для инициализации запускается временный сервер, который потом останавливается (см. https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/663). Ваше приложение стартует в момент, когда временный сервер уже остановлен, а постоянный еще не запущен. Оно не может присоединиться к mysql и вылетает. Вам нужно реализовать правильное ожидание того, что сервер стартовал.

Answer (score 1):

Роман был прав. Приложение стартовало раньше базы данных.
Помогло редактирование docker-compose.yml.
Для приложения:

```
depends_on:
         mysql:
              condition: service_healthy
```

для mysql:

```
healthcheck:
        test: "mysql -uroot -proot platform -e 'select 1'"
        interval: 1s
        retries: 120
```

Так же в в логах было: mysql Operation not permitted. Помогла следующая строчка для mysql:

```
cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
```

docker-compose.yml целиком:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nginx-server:
    restart: always
    container_name: 'nginx-server'
    image: 'hermanvfx/nginx:latest'
    depends_on:
      - front_app
    ports:
      - '80:80'

  front_app:
    container_name: 'project-avito4_1_front'
    image: 'hermanvfx/avito4_1_front:latest'
#    ports:
#      - '3000:3000'
  mysql:
    container_name: 'mysql-image'
    image: 'hermanvfx/mysql:latest'
    environment:
      - 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root'
      - 'MYSQL_DATABASE=platform'
    healthcheck:
        test: "mysql -uroot -proot platform -e 'select 1'"
        interval: 1s
        retries: 120
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE

  app:
    container_name: 'project-avito4_1_back'
    image: 'hermanvfx/avito4_1_app:latest'
    ports:
      - '8888:8888'
    depends_on:
         mysql:
              condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql-image:3306/platform?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PLATFORM=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Так же в файле docker-compose.yml изменил версию 3 на 3.7. На сервере переустановил docker-compose v1.26 на docker-compose v2.10.2